# Javascript "development" and "production

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra

I'm developing a simple application in Sinatra that makes many asynchronous calls. In my javascript code I have a variable that stores my domain for all calls. My problem is how to alter the value of the variable every time that I publish my application, for example:

```
var url = "http://localhost:9292"; //development
```

to

```
var url = "http://mysite.com" //production
```

I would like to automate this, to prevent errors in deployed application. Is it possible?

I thought about doing this in my "View" using ruby code, but do not know if it is cool.

Sorry my English.

Thanks.

Comment: Doing it in the view makes perfect sense.

Comment: Do you need to include the domain? Why not just have your links begin with a slash? Ex: href="/base-directory/some-file.htm"

Comment: In some cases yes, because I called for subsystems that use the test url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
var url = 'http://' + document.domain;
```

**document.domain** get the name of the current domain.

Comment: I had forgot to write the port, sorry. I tested this form the work if I not need use port for localhost. Do you have another sugestion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

> window.location.port

This get the domain port of the currernt website ;)

Comment: I'm using location.origin that returns "http://localhost:4567", but I think it's ugly yet.